# Rearrange a data based on one column and different similar parts

Tags: r

I have a data looks like below:

```
   1    ID_17550873     1,211752129
   2    ID_17550873     1,202295466
   3    ID_17550873     1,193705936
   4    ID_17550873     1,184065855
   5    ID_17550873     1,174741145
   6    ID_17550873     1,165991596
  54    ID_17550873.1   1,213821847
  85    ID_17550873.1   1,204415594
  82    ID_17550873.1   1,195891404
2565    ID_17550873.1   1,186352148
 236    ID_17550873.1   1,177122961
   5    ID_17550873.1   1,168398464
2123    ID_17550875     1,194476935
2124    ID_17550875     1,185464218
2125    ID_17550875     1,177338098
2126    ID_17550875     1,168257804
2127    ID_17550875     1,159501092
2128    ID_17550875     1,15130918
  25    ID_17550875.1   1,192470951
2569    ID_17550875.1   1,183321493
 512    ID_17550875.1   1,175383173
  36    ID_17550875.1   1,166816022
 578    ID_17550875.1   1,158762364
 856    ID_17550875.1   1,151287835


df<- structure(list(X1 = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 54L, 85L, 82L, 2565L, 
236L, 5L, 2123L, 2124L, 2125L, 2126L, 2127L, 2128L, 25L, 2569L, 
512L, 36L, 578L, 856L), ID_17550873 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("ID_17550873", "ID_17550873.1", "ID_17550875", 
"ID_17550875.1"), class = "factor"), X1.211752129 = c(1.202295466, 
1.193705936, 1.184065855, 1.174741145, 1.165991596, 1.213821847, 
1.204415594, 1.195891404, 1.186352148, 1.177122961, 1.168398464, 
1.194476935, 1.185464218, 1.177338098, 1.168257804, 1.159501092, 
1.15130918, 1.192470951, 1.183321493, 1.175383173, 1.166816022, 
1.158762364, 1.151287835)), .Names = c("X1", "ID_17550873", "X1.211752129"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -23L))
```

I would like to make it like below

```
ID_17550873 1,211752129 1,213821847 ID_17550875 1,194476935 1,192470951
ID_17550873 1,202295466 1,204415594 ID_17550875 1,185464218 1,183321493
ID_17550873 1,193705936 1,195891404 ID_17550875 1,177338098 1,175383173
ID_17550873 1,184065855 1,186352148 ID_17550875 1,168257804 1,166816022
ID_17550873 1,174741145 1,177122961 ID_17550875 1,159501092 1,158762364
ID_17550873 1,165991596 1,168398464 ID_17550875 1,15130918  1,151287835
```

After I loaded the data, I removed the first column. Then I put all "ID_17550873" with their corresponding values and I removed all "ID_17550873.1". I put their corresponding values in front of the "ID_17550873"

Then I do the same for other IDs

Comment: can you dput your data?

Comment: This is just for printing, right?

Comment: no, I dont want to print, I want to save it in another file to latter be able to extract it. I will try to dput it now

Comment: @Colonel Beauvel please have look at above, I dput the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option, though it's unclear to me why you would want to use such a format - I can't see any advantages.

```
library(dplyr) # for bind_cols

dd <- bind_cols(split(df[-1], df$V2))
dd[1:ncol(dd)%%4 != 3]
#           V2          V3        V3.1        V2.1        V3.2        V3.3
#1 ID_17550873 1,211752129 1,213821847 ID_17550875 1,194476935 1,192470951
#2 ID_17550873 1,202295466 1,204415594 ID_17550875 1,185464218 1,183321493
#3 ID_17550873 1,193705936 1,195891404 ID_17550875 1,177338098 1,175383173
#4 ID_17550873 1,184065855 1,186352148 ID_17550875 1,168257804 1,166816022
#5 ID_17550873 1,174741145 1,177122961 ID_17550875 1,159501092 1,158762364
#6 ID_17550873 1,165991596 1,168398464 ID_17550875  1,15130918 1,151287835
```

If you don't know the number of columns and where the ID columns with the ".X" ending are located, you can use the following approach:

```
dd <- bind_cols(split(df[-1], df$V2))  # as before
dd[!sapply(dd, function(x) any(grepl("\\..$", x)))]
```

Comment: thanks for this option but the problem is that this is only a sample of a big data, I dont know how many columns I will have ,

Comment: @Nemo, as long as they are in the same structuer, i.e. for each ID there's a part with and one without the ".1" extension, it should still work.

Comment: @Nemo, did you try to run my updated approach on your data? Please explain what happens in case it doesn't work as expected

Comment: It did not work, I uploaded a data here, please check it out https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/05e4c7cf0f3cef541ed1/raw/mym.txt

Comment: @Nemo, all you need to do is adjust the column name in the first call like this: `dd <- bind_cols(split(df[-1], df$group))` - after that it works smoothly using `res <- dd[!sapply(dd, function(x) any(grepl("\\..$", x)))]`.

Comment: actually it does not give exactly what I asked but I appreciate your valuable comment and I accept it . I just need one more favor, I try to plot it , I do wave<-seq(1,1061,by=1) then I do plot(wave,res) but it gives error in stripchart.default. do you know how to solve this ?

Comment: @Nemo, you don't have to accept it if it's not what you were asking for. But you might need to explain in more detail, what is missing or wrong.. For the plotting, I can't quite tell how you want the plot to look like (the format seems strange anyway) so it's even harder to help here. Try to be more specific, maybe someone else will understand it better